What is the difference between death and sleep as Jesus stated during time of Lazarus

John 11:11-14 CSB
He said this, and then he told them, “Our friend Lazarus has fallen
asleep, but I’m on my way to wake him up.” Then the disciples said to
him, “Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he will get well.” Jesus,
however, was speaking about his death, but they thought he was
speaking about natural sleep. So Jesus then told them plainly,
“Lazarus has died.

The ancient Greek word for sleep
The ancient meaning in literature about sleep in Greek translated to English

@Dottard, Thank you. It's kind to welcome new participants and help them formulate questions on specified scriptures.

@Dottard - apologies, you're right that I could have straightened it out myself if I'd taken a moment. We've had a number of low quality questions remaining open for weeks without VTC, so it'll take a bit of work for all of us to find the right balance. Thanks for your heart to support new visitors to the site.

In the passage quoted by the OP, John 11:11-14, there are three words used to describe death as follows:

κοιμάομαι (koimaomai, verb, V11, 12) and κοίμησις (koimesis, noun, V13)

These words mean "sleeping" and "sleep" respectively.  The cognate form of this has entered English as our word "Cemetry" = a place of sleeping.

θάνατος (thanatos, V13)

This, again has come directly into English in several forms, the most common is "euthanasia" = good death.

ἀποθνῄσκω (apothnéskó, V14)

This is essentially a strengthened form of #2 above - Jesus was saying that Lazarus was thoroughly and completely dead.  I presume that Jesus used this strengthened form of the verb to emphasize the fact of death so that there would be no doubt that He was about to perform a true miracle of raising Lazarus back to life.
It is immediately apparent that Jesus is using "sleep" as a metaphor for "death".  This is very common idiom in the NT, eg, Matt 9:24, Mark 5:39, Luke 8:52, John 11:11, 12, Acts 7:60, 13:36, 1 Cor 7:39, 11:30, 15:6, 18, 20, 51, 1 Thess 4:13-15, 5:10, 2 Peter 3:4, etc.
The metaphor of "sleep" for death emphasizes what the OT teaches about those who have died:

Eccl 9:5 - For the living know that they will die, but the dead know nothing. ...
Ps 115:17 - It is not the dead who praise the LORD, those who go down to the place of silence;

Lastly, Jesus re-emphasizes this same point when He says about Lazarus:

John 11:11 - After He had said this, He told them, “Our friend Lazarus
has fallen asleep, but I am going there to wake him up.”


To understand why Jesus referred to death as "sleep," we look at another instance for clues.

After saying these things, he said to them, “Our friend Lazarus has
fallen asleep, but I go to awaken him.” The disciples said to him,
“Lord, if he has fallen asleep, he will recover.” Now Jesus had
spoken of his death, but they thought that he meant taking rest in
sleep. Then Jesus told them plainly, “Lazarus has died, and for
your sake I am glad that I was not there, so that you may believe. But
let us go to him.” - Luke 11:11-15 ESV

Here, Jesus plainly shows that when he says that Lazarus has fallen asleep, he is introducing "sleep" as a euphemism for death, which he then clarifies for his disciples.
And continuing at verse 21 . . .

Martha said to Jesus, “Lord, if you had been here, my brother would
not have died. But even now I know that whatever you ask from God,
God will give you.” Jesus said to her, “Your brother will rise
again.” Martha said to him, “I know that he will rise again in the
resurrection on the last day.” Jesus said to her, “I am the
resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in me, though he die,
yet shall he live, and everyone who lives and believes in me shall
never die.

From this passage, we see that Martha understands that people are raised at the resurrection. From the words of Jesus, we can then can clearly conclude that people who put their trust in Jesus won't die, but they should be considered as merely asleep until they are resurrected.
Then to demonstrate that these aren't merely empty words but that he has the power of resurrection, Jesus raises Lazarus from the dead.
